# Difference between arrow functions and functions when using decorators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, this, settimeout, arrow-functions

I'm sort of new to JavaScript and currently working out how dynamic scoping works. Now I understand how `this` gets its value. I've read all the rules and understand most of them, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this piece of code that explains the difference between using arrow functions and functions in decorators. 
Here's the link to the code https://javascript.info/arrow-functions.

The code with arrow functions

```
function defer(f, ms) {
  return function() {
    //What is this? Why use apply? 
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, arguments), ms)
  };
}

function sayHi(who) {
  alert('Hello, ' + who);
}

let sayHiDeferred = defer(sayHi, 2000);
sayHiDeferred("John"); // Hello, John after 2 seconds
```

And with normal functions

```
function defer(f, ms) {
  return function(...args) {
    // What's the purpose of this line? 
    let ctx = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
     // Again why apply? 
      return f.apply(ctx, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}
```

Here's what I have trouble understanding.

1. Why are we even using `apply` in both cases? Can't we do it without apply?
2. What would happen if I simply call `f` instead of using `f.apply`?
3. Are we using `apply` because of `setTimeOut`?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The point of using `apply` is to control what `this` will be.

Comment: Because functions called by *setTimeout* and *setInterval* do not have their *this* set, so it will be *undefined* in strict mode or the global object otherwise. The *defer* function sets the *this* of the deferred function to the same *this* as *defer* was called with, so the caller can control the value of *this* in the deferred function.

Answer (score 2):

Solid questions - and honestly - a good sign you're thinking.

> Why are we even using apply in both cases? Can't we do it without apply?

Its worth knowing `.apply` (and its sibling `.bind`) are from a time where we didn't have arrow functions that *auto-bind* the "this" context.  So, just know that - they're from and older time.

Now,  what are they for (apply/bind)? You really only need them when you want to assign "this". In the cases you presented, you're not referencing `this` - meaning you'd have the same outcome if you simply invoked the functions normally.  This also addresses your question:

> What would happen if I simply call f instead of using f.apply?

Nothing. You'd have the same outcome.

> Are we using apply because of setTimeOut?

It looks like you're taking some examples you've seen around the internets - but the short answer is: *Yes, you'd use . `.apply` or `.bind` when because of setTimeOut*. But the example you provided hides the actual lesson.

Here's an attempt.

```js
function iReferenceThisForStuff() {
    console.log(this.foo)
}

setTimeout(iReferenceThisForStuff, 10)

// ...10ms pass

// "undefined" is logged because "this" references the global window object
```

In the above example we passed a non-bound function to the timeout, and logged `window.foo` because - when not set explicitly - `this` is a reference to the global scope.  This is a fallback behavior, very weird - but it's how it works.

Working with `.bind` and `.apply` examples:

```js
function iReferenceThisForStuff() {
    console.log(this.foo)
}

setTimeout(iReferenceThisForStuff.bind({ foo: "bar" }), 10)

// ...10ms pass

// "bar" is logged because "this" references the object reference passed to `.bind`

// You could have also done...

setTimeout(function () {
   return iReferenceThisForStuff.apply({ foo: "bar" }, /* maybe some additional args */)
}, 10)

// and you would have the same outcome.
```

Final note on arrow functions. They bind `this` as whatever `this` is in the closure from which they are instantiated.

```
(function () {
   setTimeOut(() => { // This arrow function is instantiated in a closure where `this` is a reference to { foo: "bar" } and is automatically bound.
       console.log(this.foo) // Will eventually log "bar"
   })
}.bind({ foo: "bar" }))
```

Comment: "when not set explicitly - this is a reference to the global scope" no, it's a reference to the global object itself, and when in strict mode, it's *undefined*. ;-) *this* actually has nothing to do with scope since it's always resolved in the current execution context. Except for arrow functions, when it's resolved to the *this* of an outer execution context via the lexical scope chain.